# At time t minutes, the volume of rain water in the pit is $V$ meter cubic and the depth of rain water in the tank is $x$ meter.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A water tank has horizontal base of 75 m by 20 m. Pumps are installed
>   in the pit to avoid overflowing of water. At time $t$ minutes after
>   the start of the test, rain water is released into the tank at a rate
>   of $600e^{-\frac{t}{20}}$ cubic meters per minute and the pump will
>   remove the rainwater at a rate of $30te^{-\frac{t}{20}}$  cubic meter
>   per minute. Initially, the depth of the rain water in the tank is 0.1
>   meters. At time t minutes, the volume of rain water in the pit is $V$
>   meter cubic and the depth of rain water in the tank is $h$ meter.
>   Formulate a ode relating the height $h$ and the time $t$.

Do i model the ode as $$\dfrac{dV}{dt} =600e^{-\frac{t}{20}} -30te^{-\frac{t}{20}} $$ and solve it? Then i use chain rule $$\dfrac{dV}{dt} = \dfrac{dV}{dh} \cdot \dfrac{dh}{dt} $$ where $$\dfrac{dV}{dh} = 75 \times 20?$$

Can anyone help me with this. The answer is $$\dfrac{dh}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{p}e^{-\frac{1}{20}}(20-t)$$ where $p$ is a constant to be determined.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- $V=Ah=1500h$

then

- $\dfrac{dV}{dt} =600e^{-\frac{t}{20}} -30te^{-\frac{t}{20}}\implies \dfrac{dh}{dt} =\frac25e^{-\frac{t}{20}} -\frac1{50}te^{-\frac{t}{20}}=\frac1{50}e^{-\frac{t}{20}}(20-t)$